# Parse JSON data with objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, dictionary

I am trying to practice parsing jSON data using the youTube most popular feed and use the values to plug into a tableview.

Here is my code to GET:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setTimeoutInterval:15.0];

_jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    if (connectionError == NULL)
    {
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&connectionError];

        NSDictionary *firstlayer = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];

        NSDictionary *secondLayer = [firstlayer objectForKey:@"entry"];

        _jsonArray = [secondLayer valueForKey:@"title"];

        NSLog(@"%@",_jsonArray);


        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Connection failed, please try again later");
    }
}];
```

Here is the response:

```
2015-02-12 11:37:44.679 RestDemo[27043:2384786] (
        {
        "$t" = "Steven Yeun & Conan Visit A Korean Spa  - CONAN on TBS";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Woman in minivan stops high speed chase in Dallas - 2/11/15";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Anything Can Be Sexy with Dakota Johnson";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Pitch Perfect 2 \U2013 Official Trailer 2 (HD)";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Bill Belichick Talks About Deflategate with David Letterman";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "\"Trainwreck\" Official Red Band Trailer";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "TRAINWRECK Trailer #1 (2015) Judd Apatow Comedy Movie HD";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "HEAT MAP Microwave- a NEW invention";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "The Transgender Fight For Safe Bathrooms";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "This Is SportsCenter - Sharks";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "23 Weird Awards - mental_floss on YouTube - List Show (246)";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Honest Trailers - Boyhood";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Dr. Phil on Punishment Haircuts";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Calvin Harris - Pray to God ft. HAIM";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Understanding Boko Haram";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Guys Read Each Other\U2019s Texts To Their Girlfriends | Elite Daily";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Here\U2019s the first behind the scenes footage of SPECTRE.";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "STAR WARS - CROSSGUARD LIGHTSABER";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Florence + The Machine - How Big How Blue How Beautiful";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "DSCOVR Launches Aboard SpaceX Falcon 9";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Sergei Polunin, \"Take Me to Church\" by Hozier, Directed by David LaChapelle";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "What Are Measles Parties?";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Sevyn Streeter - Don't Kill The Fun ft. Chris Brown [Official Video]";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "Sia - Chandelier (57th GRAMMYs feat. Kristen Wiig & Maddie Ziegler)";
    },
        {
        "$t" = "50 Shades of Buscemi (Trailer Recut)";
    }
)
```

How can I unwrap it from this array to assign them into a tableview.

Comment: You can "assign" that array to a tableView right now -- there's no restriction on what you can use for a dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Ups, I will edit:

To show your JSON array in a table view you have to use UITableView delegate and data source.

```
 self.tableView.delegate = self;
 self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

And then implement tableview data sources and delegates:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return _jsonArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
   if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"] autorelease];
   cell.textLabel.text = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:row];
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again. The output shown in the question is the `_jsonArray`. Besides, the question isn't about parsing the JSON. It's an overly broad question about getting the obtained array of data into a table view.